# Filtering an NSArray with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray that I would like to filter with a predicate. Here is what I have.

```
NSLog(@"text is %@",txtSearch.text);
NSPredicate *bPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '%@'",txtSearch.text];
arrSearchedPlayers =
[arrPlayers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
NSLog(@"array after searched is %@",arrSearchedPlayers);
```

When I enter a text my array keeps empty. But when I try this predicate,

```
 NSPredicate *bPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 's'"];
```

I got the right results.Anybody has an idea what the problem is?

Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove extra quotes in predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",txtSearch.text];
```